# What is the gradle dependency for J/Link?

Tags: java

After much googling, browsing several answers on MathematicaSE as well as going through the J/Link docs, I haven't figured out the Gradle dependency for `com.wolfram.jlink.*`. What is it?

Searching on Maven doesn't turn up anything. In case it hadn't been published via Maven, the docs don't mention any download mirrors. What's going on? How does one acquire the official J/Link `jar`?

**Env:**
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Mathematica: 12

Comment: On Windows, I think it's in `C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\13.2\SystemFiles\Links\JLink` directory.

Comment: And on Ubuntu, *usually* at, `/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.2/SystemFiles/Links/JLink`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the JLink jar file is shipped with Mathematica. The location is subject to change based on installation and platform, so use the following code to find it on your system:

If you have version 12.3+ use:

```
ExternalEvaluate["Java", "
new java.io.File(com.wolfram.jlink.StdLink.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
    .toURI()).getPath();
"]
```

For others use:

```
Needs["JLink`"];

JavaBlock[
 JavaNew["java.io.File", 
   JavaNew["com.wolfram.jlink.StdLink"]@
    getClass[]@
     getProtectionDomain[]@getCodeSource[]@getLocation[]@toURI[]]@
  getPath[]
 ]
```

Both return `C:\Program Files\Wolfram\Research\Mathematica\13.2\SystemFiles\Links\JLink\JLink.jar` on my system.

Comment: I was looking more for a published dependency, to be Gradle managed, but for the time being a local jar will do, especially if it came packaged with the software. Thanks.